# Web API parameter not deserializing (is null) when XML element is missing

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a model defined for my web API:

```
public class MyRequest
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public short? location { get; set; }
}
```

The function takes the model as the parameter:

```
public MyResponse Post(MyRequest request)
{
    ...
    doSomeStuff();
    ...
}
```

I want both the name and location properties of the model to be optional. If they aren't passed in, the function should see them as null and evaluate them as such.

This is working fine when data is passed in as JSON:

```
{
    "id":100,
    "location":1
}
```

The request is deserialized and the object has an ID of 100, null for the name, and a location of 1.

However, this does not work for XML:

```
<MyRequest>
    <id>100</id>
    <location>1</location>
</MyRequest>
```

The request object is null - I assume because the object fails to deserialize. If I add the missing element to the XML request, it works correctly. So I know the function and the formatting of the XML/call is correct. It's only a problem when an element is missing.

I've tried adding the `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]` to the properties I wish to make optional, but that makes no difference.

Note: I am using XmlSerializer, rather than the default DataContractSerializer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.